# XMPP group chat - Room members Always return zero

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, smack

**Room configuration when creating new room.**

```
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_passwordprotectedroom", false);
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_changesubject", true);
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_allowinvites", true);
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_membersonly", false);
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_moderatedroom", false);
submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomowners", owners);
muc.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);
```

**In group Chat Activity when i try bellow methods for members and owners all return zero**

```
List<Affiliate> affiliatesMem =   room.getMembers();
List<Occupant> affiliatesMem1 =   room.getParticipants();
List<EntityFullJid> affiliatesMem2 =   room.getOccupants();
List<Affiliate> affiliatesAdmin = room.getAdmins();

Is i need to do some thing extra?

Thanks
```

Comment: check your rooster sharing options, its different for different servers, but if you dont enable rooster sharing on your server it wont show the things you expect.

Comment: I did not find such kind of setting in openfire server, any link how to enable rooster sharing setting.

Comment: in openfire click on the group name you created, then go to edit group and scroll down you would see Contact List (Roster) Sharing , just enable it

Comment: in openfire click on the group name you created or if you don't have a group create one and put them as part of your muc members,owners or admin, then go to edit group and scroll down you would see Contact List (Roster) Sharing , just enable it